# How to export SJCL AES key back to raw format?

Tags: sjcl

After I imported [SJCL](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl) AES key using `new sjcl.cipher.aes(rawKey)`, how can I get `rawKey` value back from the key instance?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not easily possible.
Looking at the code, the key is immediatly transformed using the S-Box. The result ist stored in `this._key`, so you could get that result and then use the reverse S-Box to restore `rawKey`. This should work, but just storing the key in a variable is of course way simpler.